# What is the purpose of using quote_id_mask Table?

Tags: magento2, quote

What is the purpose of using quote_id_mask Table ?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the history for this implementation [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commits/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteIdMask.php). Likely, its done to prevent sequential ID attacks. (Bots have a harder time collecting quote data en masse now because the masks are not as predictable as IDs.)

Answer (score 2):

Unknown users cannot obtain private information of your registered customers. It doesn’t include the cart_id_mask value in the quote_id_mask table, it makes difficult for hackers to obtain information of your registered users.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think this table comes in action when any guest customer add product in their cart. Magento saves masked id with quote id. masked_id is stored in local storage as well.

check below code

**webapi.xml**

```
<route url="/V1/guest-carts/:cartId" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Quote\Api\GuestCartRepositoryInterface" method="get"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous" />
    </resources>
</route>
```

**GuestCartRepositoryInterface.php**

```
public function get($cartId)
{
    /** @var $quoteIdMask QuoteIdMask */
    $quoteIdMask = $this->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($cartId, 'masked_id');
    return $this->quoteRepository->get($quoteIdMask->getQuoteId());
}
```

magento use masked_id to fetch quote id then fetch quote using quote_id for guest customer.